# А вы подписываете свои коммиты в git?

Tags: git, безопасность, gpg, rsa, signature

А вы подписываете свои коммиты в git?

Comment: @deterok, а Вы когда научитесь писать слово "ко**мм**ит" правильно?

Comment: вы не можете решить, подписывать вам или нет, без помощи сообщества?

Comment: Да нет, просто хотел узнать, кто вообще подписывает и насколько эта практика распространена на территории России и СНГ.

Comment: @romeo, транслитизация требует точного повторения набора символов исходного слова?

А вообщем да, обычно пишут с двумя "м".

Comment: в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет.

А у вас много тех, кто может проверить подпись?

Если потырят приватный ключ с паролем на него, который используется для пуша в git репозиторий, так вполне могут потырить и pgp ключ для подписи коммитов.

Comment: Да, целых 3 человека :)

А можно подробнее логику того, как вы представляете себе потерю ключа?

К тому же я использую разные подключи на разных машинах.

Comment: А можно поподробнее о том, что вы имеете в виду под "логикой"? Украли один из ваших ключей, и пароль на него, на той же машине, где есть и ключевая пара для пуша в репозиторий, и пароль на её приватный ключ. Вы всё ещё можете подписывать, но может и кто-то ещё, и пушить. Отозвать скомпрометированный ключ быстро - проблематично.

Comment: Эм, заменить его?

Или я что-то не понимаю, или вы :)

В чем проблема менять подключи как перчатки? Что-то не так? Меняешь, чувствуешь, что мог "посеять"?  Меняешь. Главное не потерять мастер-ключ, а то все ключи придется менять и перераздавать публичный.

Comment: И что, украденным подключём после этого уже нельзя будет подписать?